# how to let Dockerfile COPY samba path file

Tags: docker, samba

I have a file from samba. I would like to build my own Dockerfile to COPY this file from samba during first init docker build. Is it possible to include samba link into Dockerfile? Or I really have to mount that samba link outside and do a simple COPY in Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker can access the network while building your `Dockerfile`. So, theoretically, it can access your file from Samba.

However, you'll have to have a Samba client installed and configured *inside* your build. Something like this:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install samba && \
    somehow_configure_samba && \
    smbget ... smb://host/share/path/to/file && \
    apt-get remove --purge samba
```

The configuration, however, might not be trivial, since the build will most likely be running in a sandboxed network.

Comment: let me try smbget, previous i tried wget but it does not support samba.

Answer (score 0):

if its a file and it can be access directly. .i suppose it could be copied during image build using `COPY /smb/mount/dir/*file` to `/dir/inside/container`
edit:

right. .sorry.  u already know this. .this is not what u mean. .
i dont really know what u mean tho. .do you mean like u want to mount it when u `docker run -v /smb/mount/dir:/smb`

Comment: My case is just copy the file ONCE to init my docker container. so i will not mount that volume.